# How to calculate slope and intercept for every row in different columns

Tags: r, row, linear-regression

I am trying to calculate the slope and intercept for every row in different columns in a dataframe. The output (intercept and slope) should be added to the original data frame as new columns.

To be as clear as possible of what I am trying to achieve, I have provided some of my data below:

```
locations<-c("a","b","c")

proportion.I<-c(0.073846154, 0.079710145, 0.063218391)

proportion.II<-c(0.049773659, 0.033756955, 0.011237956)

proportion.III<-c(0.090322581, 0.100917431, 0.08051443)

abundance.I<-c(331,331,331)

abundance.II<-c(178,178,178)

abundance.III<-c(87,87,87)

output.slope<-c(5.539e-05, -4.665e-05, -2.819e-05)

output.intercept<-c(5.128e-02, 8.073e-02, 5.726e-02)

df<-data.frame(locations, proportion.I, proportion.II, proportion.III, abundance.I, abundance.II, abundance.III, output.slope, output.intercept)
```

*The 'dependent' variables for my linear regression will be 'Proportion' (rows 2:4) and the predictor (or independent) variables will be 'abundance' (rows 5:7).

Comment: Are you sure those are the correct "output.slope" and `output.intercept` values for your data? The first row would be `x <- c(0.073846154,0.049773659,0.090322581); y <- c(331,178,87); summary(lm(y~x))`, correct? That doesn't seem to be the value you are showing.

Comment: Hi MrFlick. Yes, you are absolutely right. I just corrected it. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your data is not in a "tidy" format which makes it difficult to use most built in functions. You can use `dplyr` and `tidyr` to transorm your data into a share that makes it easier to do group-wise regressions. For example

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  select(-starts_with("output")) %>%                   #drop "answers"
  pivot_longer(proportion.I:abundance.III) %>%         # convert to long format
  separate(name, into = c("var", "idx")) %>%           # get values from column names
  pivot_wider(names_from=var, values_from=value) %>%   # go back to wide
  nest(data=-locations) %>%                             
  mutate(reg = map(data, ~lm(abundance~proportion, .))) %>%   # do the regression
  mutate(intercept=map_dbl(reg, ~coefficients(.)[1]),         # get values form regression
         slope=map_dbl(reg, ~coefficients(.)[2]))
```

This matches the values your provided, but from your description it would seem that you want the regression the other way: `~lm(proportion~abundance, .)`

Comment: This is great. Is there a way to turn the tibble back to a data frame? I tried doing df<-as.data.frame(df) but it isn't really working.

Comment: A `tibble` is a basically data.frame. Why do you need to change it? They behave the same in most cases. You could add `select(-data, -reg) %>% as.data.frame()` to the end of the chain to clean things up if it's really necessary.

Comment: Terrific. It works perfectly. Thank you very much, MrFlick!

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in a `for` loop with `base R`.  Create a `NULL` `list` with the `length` equal to the number of rows of dataset ('out') to store the output.  Get the names of 'proportion', 'abundance' columns in the dataset ('prp', 'abn').  Loop over the row sequence of the dataset, extract the 'prp', 'abn' columns, create a model with `lm`, extract the coefficients, and assign it to `list` element of 'out'.  Finally, `rbind` the `list` elements and assign it to new columns in the original dataset

```
out <- vector('list', nrow(df))
prp <- names(df)[startsWith(names(df), "proportion")]
abn <- names(df)[startsWith(names(df), "abundance")]
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df)))  out[[i]] <- coef(lm(abundance ~ proportion,
   data.frame(abundance = unlist(df[i, abn]), proportion = unlist(df[i, prp]))))

df[c('slope', 'intercept')] <- do.call(rbind, out)[,2:1]
df[, c("slope", "intercept")]
#       slope intercept
#1 -1613.9597  313.7648
#2  -601.7193  241.6664
#3  -329.6502  215.6954
```